# how to fix "FFmpeg cannot edit existing files in-place."-Problem in Java

Tags: java, ffmpeg

I am trying to write an audio file to an existing videofile. Unfortunately I get the Logmessage, that I cannot edit existing files in-place.

I have found some threads about the so called muxing between video and audio, but none of them could help me out really. Maybe some one of you can.
Further this isn`t my could either. I am only the one who needs to use it, so I have to fix it.

Thanks for your help

```
String[] args = { FFMPEG_FILE.getAbsolutePath(), "-y", "-i", videoPath, "-ss", String.valueOf(-offset.toFrames() / 50.0f), "-i", audioPath, "-c", "copy", "-map", "0:v", "-map","1:a", "-bsf:v", "h264_mp4toannexb","-r", String.valueOf(project.getFramerate()), "-shortest",outputPath };

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(args).inheritIO();
Process p = pb.start();
int exit = p.waitFor();
if (exit != 0) {
     throw new IOException("ffmpeg terminated with a failure");
}
```

EDIT: As someone commented outputPath was same same as videopath. So switched it to another, so this problem would not appear again. But I still have no sound in my outputvideos. I give you the LOG-information, so maybe you can read something out of it.

```
INFO: start ffmpeg: [C:\Program Files\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe, -y, -i, C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\Test_Workflow\1.mkv, -ss, 0.0, -i, C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\Test\resources/videos/P1000501.MP4\audio.ogg, -c, copy, -map, 0:v, -map, 1:a, -bsf:v, h264_mp4toannexb, -r, 25, -shortest, C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\Test\testoutput.mp4]
ffmpeg version N-92087-gdcbd89e000 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.2.1 (GCC) 20180813
  configuration: --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 19.101 / 56. 19.101
  libavcodec     58. 31.102 / 58. 31.102
  libavformat    58. 18.104 / 58. 18.104
  libavdevice    58.  4.105 / 58.  4.105
  libavfilter     7. 33.100 /  7. 33.100
  libswscale      5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
  libswresample   3.  2.100 /  3.  2.100
  libpostproc    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\Test_Workflow\1.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf56.4.101
  Duration: 00:00:04.60, start: 0.080000, bitrate: 1377 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
Input #1, ogg, from 'C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\Test\resources/videos/P1000501.MP4\audio.ogg':
  Duration: 00:04:20.65, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 86 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(und): Audio: vorbis, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 112 kb/s
    Metadata:
      CREATION_TIME   : 2018-11-09T13:20:07.000000Z
      LANGUAGE        : und
      ENCODER         : Lavc58.31.102 libvorbis
      MAJOR_BRAND     : mp42
      MINOR_VERSION   : 1
      COMPATIBLE_BRANDS: mp42avc1
[mp4 @ 000001e67c0a00c0] track 1: codec frame size is not set
Output #0, mp4, to 'C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\Test\testoutput.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.18.104
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: vorbis (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 112 kb/s
    Metadata:
      CREATION_TIME   : 2018-11-09T13:20:07.000000Z
      LANGUAGE        : und
      ENCODER         : Lavc58.31.102 libvorbis
      MAJOR_BRAND     : mp42
      MINOR_VERSION   : 1
      COMPATIBLE_BRANDS: mp42avc1
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  113 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=     824kB time=00:00:04.41 bitrate=1530.8kbits/s speed= 634x    
video:772kB audio:43kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:4kB muxing overhead: 1.092082%
```

Comment: What the values of `videoPath` and `outputPath` ? It seems they're same, but `ffmpeg` can't overwrite (edit in-place) a file used as input.

Comment: thank you. yes you were right with that. I just corrected it.

Comment: Another comment: If I change the outputformat to "mkv" the muxing overhead is under 1% and I get the audio onto the video. With mp4 it does not work. But thats the format I would like it to be.

Comment: For the audio problem I have no idea, sorry. The log is saying everything was fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the original issue, "FFmpeg cannot edit existing files in-place.", that was put in place since ffmpeg needs to read the input, so it can't replace the input at the same time.

For the current issue, vorbis is not a standard audio codec for MP4, so re-encode the audio.

`C:\Program Files\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe, -y, -i, C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\Test_Workflow\1.mkv, -ss, 0.0, -i, C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\Test\resources/videos/P1000501.MP4\audio.ogg, -c:v, copy, -map, 0:v, -map, 1:a, -r, 25, -shortest, C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\Test\testoutput.mp4`

(Since you're writing to MP4, `-bsf:v, h264_mp4toannexb` is the opposite of what you want, and is not needed here)